# C# kick off an import process to run in the background

Tags: c#, asynchronous

What is the proper way in C# now days to kick off a process to run in the background while returning immediately to the UI thread?

After I obtain the history id, then I want to kick off the process in the background. Then return the history id back to the UI thread to that I can continue to watch for the process to finish in the background.

The process could take 10 seconds or 5 minutes -> based on how big a file they are uploading to import.

I've read around and maybe `Task.Run()` will take care of it? Not sure though?

```
          Task.Run(() => ProcessImport(submitImportItemsAndProcessImport.ImportDetailId, importMetricId, currentUserId));
```

Here is the error:

> Error  CS4014  Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call. WebPortal.MVC

I don't want to await it though because I want the HistoryId to be returned immediately to the UI thread.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can ignore that compiled time warning; although you will definitely want to monitor the task.

Comment: I think you have a larger design problem - you want to avoid having web operations that take ~5 minutes to complete.  1) Clients will most likely get timeout errors 2) until you job completes you waste a thread on the web server unless your MVC controller is already async

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how your web UI is going to _"...watch for the process to finish..."_ going by what you have said with discarding `await`.

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET application? If it is, check out this: [Fire and Forget on ASP.NET](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine to ignore the warning... However, if like me you have warning OCD you can use a discard to tell the compiler to ignore the warning

_ = ProcessImport(submitImportItemsAndProcessImport.ImportDetailId, importMetricId, currentUserId);

Having said that, some form of progress reporter will be needed to inform you when the process has completed, this could be in the form of an IProgress implementation passed into your async method or an invoke call on a method...

Answer (score 1):

You have warn as error set to true in project settings. It is normally a warning otherwise, and can be ignored at will.